# How to partition disk for manjaro?

Tags: partitioning, manjaro

I am trying to dual-boot manjaro kde and windows 10 on separate hard drives. I want to have a separate home partition and i am on an EFI system. I do not think i want swap. The disk for manjaro is 250GB. How do i partition it? The partitioning should be done in the manjaro kde installer. I tried to use a 512mb partition mounted at `/boot/efi` tagged boot and the rest of the space for one partition tagged root mounted at `/` and one just mounted at `/home`, but that did not work and i was thrown into a grub shell and stuff. Could have done something else wrong, but i still want tips.

Comment: No, you should use the existing ESP (you cam create another but it can be problematic). And there's really no good reason nowadays to have a separated /home (you should have backups anyway; a separated partition is NOT a backup!). So, do yourself a favor and **1. understand that you MUST disable Windows' Fast Startup** before installing and 2. Let the  Manjaro installer do its thing.

Comment: I'd suggest to use an actual physical disk as /home: much easier in case you need to "fiddle" with the OS; You cannot re-use the settings/config files, but everything else is (semi-) safe - just by picking out the disk.

Comment: I only have 2 physical disks, one is fully taken by windows. The separated home is for easier replacement of the distro.

Comment: I also have managed to dual boot the same windows system and ubuntu with default partitioning.